# iOS dismiss a chain of ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I'm a bit puzzled by the following behavior in iOS (target is iPad with iOS 9.3 in Xcode 7.3.1). I have the following hierarchy:

```
Storyboard1
|
| initial
|
A (UIViewController)
|
| UIStoryboardSegue Present Modally
|
B (UINavigationController)
|
| root
|
C (UIViewController)
|
| presentViewController
|
Storyboard2
|
| initial
|
D (UIViewController)
|
| UIStoryboardSegue Present Modally
|
E (UIViewController) here
```

When `E` completes, I want to go back to `A`, so I thought about using `self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil)` in `C`, which I call from `E` by keeping a weak reference to `C`, but that brings me back to `C` and not `A`. If I want to go back to `A` I have to issue the same dismiss command twice. What am I missing?

Comment: how about use unwind segue? E to  A this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: @SwiftyCruz great suggestion! Make it an answer, and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wolfy,

Simply call,

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

**How it works**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController will return `A (UIViewController)`
```

since A ViewController has modally presented `B (UINavigationController)` and all other viewControllers are loaded in this navigation stack dismissing `B (UINavigationController)` will unload all the viewControllers for you :)

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

To dismiss multiple modals you can do this :

```
A.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,nil)
```